# Type shown on mouseover

Tags: feature-request, documentation, markdown, syntax-section

**Disclaimer**: this is only appealing for dynamically typed languages.

It would be cool to have the return and parameter types of the signatures in the syntax section appear when you mouse over the function name and the parameters respectively. Whatever you choose for the syntactic sugar should be something that is not common in a signature.

e.g. `functionName(parameterName[[TypeName]])[[returnType]]`

I don't want the documentation to support a specific convention.
For example, if rtype was the defacto standard for the JS signatures we would still have the problem of the screen real estate: signatures with types are too long and ultimately hurt the readability.